# Double-checked locking not thread-safe?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, memory, thread-safety, locking

I've experienced a very odd behavior in a WPF application, when I was using  double-checked locking to create a thread-safe singleton. My code represents a usual implementation of that technique:

```
  Private _graphics As Contracts.Interfaces.Components.IGraphics
    ReadOnly Property Graphics As Contracts.Interfaces.Components.IGraphics
        Get
            If _graphics Is Nothing Then
                SyncLock lock
                    If (_graphics Is Nothing) Then
                        _graphics = New GFX.Application()
                    End If
                End SyncLock
            End If
            Return _graphics
        End Get
    End Property
```

When I was running the program, I got an exception, because the Application-object was constructed twice. I couldn't believe my eyes, since my understanding of how locks work, tells me that this should be thread-safe.

My presumption was, that this code was running twice on the same thread (asynchronously), so I ended up modifying my code to analyse this problem. I was adding a List in order to put a Thread-object into it every time a thread steps into the locking statement. Next, I just had to compare the contained Thread-object with the current thread:

```
ReadOnly Property Graphics As Contracts.Interfaces.Components.IGraphics
    Get
        If _graphics Is Nothing Then
            SyncLock lock
                If (_graphics Is Nothing) Then
                    If (threadList.Any() AndAlso (threadList.First() IsNot Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)) Then
                        Stop ' Program is stopping here.
                    End If
                    threadList.Add(Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
                    _graphics = New GFX.Application() ' Object construction takes around 70 ms.
                End If
            End SyncLock
        End If
        Return _graphics
    End Get
End Property
```

As you might guess, the program stopped, because multiple threads ran into the same locking statement. How can this be true? I have absolutely no explanation for this behavior, let me know if you have any idea. thanks.

**UPDATE**:
I want to add some more details. This is the initialization routine that causes two anonymous methods to run asynchronously. Each of them accesses the readonly property of the Singleton holder.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Graphics.Init(...)
 Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Graphics.Run(...)
```

And here are the related disassembly instructions. Perhaps they give an indication. Is anybody here able to follow these instructions:

```
 If _graphics Is Nothing Then
002D91ED  cmp         dword ptr ds:[38E3430h],0  
002D91F4  sete        al  
002D91F7  movzx       eax,al  
002D91FA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
002D91FD  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-48h],0  
002D9201  je          002D9297  
                SyncLock lock
002D9207  nop  
002D9208  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[038E3438h]  
002D920D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  
002D9210  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
002D9213  call        518DCE8C  
002D9218  nop  
002D9219  xor         edx,edx  
002D921B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],edx  
002D921E  nop  
002D921F  lea         edx,[ebp-44h]  
002D9222  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
002D9225  call        7301A2B0  
002D922A  nop  
                    If _graphics Is Nothing Then
002D922B  cmp         dword ptr ds:[38E3430h],0  
002D9232  sete        al  
002D9235  movzx       eax,al  
002D9238  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
002D923B  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-48h],0  
002D923F  je          002D9264  
                        _graphics = New GFX.Application()
002D9241  mov         ecx,47D664h  
002D9246  call        73E601D2  
002D924B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
002D924E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
002D9251  call        002D8C10  
002D9256  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
002D9259  lea         edx,ds:[38E3430h]  
002D925F  call        73E52360  
                    End If
002D9264  nop  
                End SyncLock
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C#.

Comment: You are accessing `_graphics` outside the SyncLock, in the code just after `Get` (the `If` statement).

Comment: This is okay. It should be locked only in case it is null. Because of the locking statement a Memory Barrier is processed and _graphics will return  a reliable value. Also no second thread should be able to enter the statement, so that it should be impossible for threads to create multiple instances.

Comment: Intellitrace would give you more info

Comment: Our company uses VS Professional, so we can't use Intellitrace. On a second system (my private computer) I couldn't reproduce this behavior. Tomorrow when being back at work, I will continue analysing this behavior.

Comment: I've added the disassemby instructions in the hope to get an explanation.